# AWS ECS Fargate Container Stops Running Without Errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

[image: latest code logs]

I'm facing an issue with my AWS ECS Fargate setup, and I'm seeking some guidance. I've set up a container for web scraping that tends to run for about 2-5 hours and then mysteriously stops without any errors in the logs. I initially believed the cluster, task definition, and task were correctly configured, but now I'm not entirely sure.

Here are some key points:

**Task Behavior**: The container runs smoothly for a while, and then it stops showing logs. I can confirm that the program has halted because no further updates are happening to the database.

**Task Status**: Interestingly, the task status remains as "RUNNING" even when no logs are being produced.

**Logs and Errors**: Surprisingly, there are no errors reported in the logs when the container stops. It's as if the program just halts abruptly.

**Resource Utilization**: I considered CPU or memory issues, but Container Insights shows that I'm not reaching the reserved limits. Additionally, when the program stops showing logs, CPU usage drops close to 0.

I initially suspected a potential bug in the code, but when I ran the container locally, it executed successfully until completion.

I'm a bit puzzled about what might be causing this unexpected behavior. If anyone has insights or suggestions regarding my ECS Fargate settings or potential issues, I'd greatly appreciate your help! Feel free to ask for additional details on my configuration.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It really sounds like a code/software problem. Are you sure there aren't other memory limits your software is hitting? Some software, like Java for example, won't always use all the memory available on the system unless you configure it to. So your software could be hitting some internal memory limit.

Comment: @MarkB Apologies for the delay, I was redoing some tests. The software doesn't appear to be hitting any limits. Along with CloudWatch metrics, I integrated a routine in the code to print CPU and memory usage every 15 seconds. Even after the code stops executing, the monitoring logs persist (refer to the screenshot of the latest code logs). Following the code's cessation, CPU usage gradually approaches 0.